# JOGL display function got called twice

Tags: java, frame, jogl

I'm very new to JOGL, hence please pardon the question's noobness.

I'm trying to write a piece of toy code to output a single square using GLCanvas, which is positioned randomly on the canvas. However, the display function seems to get called twice (and hence two squares appear, rather than one). Here's the code. Where did I go wrong?

RandomPoint class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;


public class RandomPoints extends Frame implements GLEventListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int HEIGHT;
    public int WIDTH;
    private GLCanvas canvas;
    //private Animator animator;
    public RandomPoints(){
        HEIGHT = 300;
        WIDTH = 300;
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities cap = new GLCapabilities(profile);
        canvas = new GLCanvas(cap);
        add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        System.out.println("Probe");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                //animator.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });     
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GL2 gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
        float red = (float) Math.random();
        float blue = (float) Math.random();
        float green = (float) Math.random();
        int x = (int)(Math.random()*WIDTH);
        int y = (int)(Math.random()*HEIGHT);
        gl.glColor3f(red, green, blue);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
            gl.glVertex2i(x, y);
            gl.glVertex2i(x+10, y);
            gl.glVertex2i(x+10, y+10);
            gl.glVertex2i(x, y+10);
        gl.glEnd();
        System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+red+" "+green+" "+blue);



    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GL2 gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //animator = new Animator(canvas);
        //animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WIDTH = arg3; HEIGHT = arg4;
        GL2 gl = arg0.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(0, WIDTH, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1);
    }

}
```

GLTest class (driver)

```
public class GLTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RandomPoints point = new RandomPoints();
        point.setSize(300,300);
        point.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code and I see only one square. However, it would be better to clear the color buffer in the display() method too. You should look at my example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOGL#Code_example). If you really want to animate your drawing, you should use an animator. Please rather post your questions about JOGL on its [official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org) if you want to get more accurate and faster replies as only a very few maintainers come here.